# How not to displease Lord Hanuman

Tags: hanuman, bhakti

I am a great devotee of Lord Hanuman and want to be careful with my actions. I want to know, being a devotee of Lord Hanuman what things should I avoid which might displease him.

Comment: The first and foremost thing being a Hanuman Devotee is BrahmaCharya or Celibacy. There is no point of any sexual desires or wantings or acts. And for a Hanuman Devotee it is also not hard to give up sexual desires.

Comment: Also please don't get perplex that no sexual activity means that if you are being taught about reproduction in biology class, so you start fearing, and other such cases. You just avoid sexual activities like any other thing. It is like it does not matter to a Hanuman Bhakta to do small things like sexual courtings.